# how can I solve "Cannot redeclare class" error in zf2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm developing a personal finance application with ZF2 in ZendStudio 11. I'm getting the following fatal error after adding a new controller from **New Zend Item** wizard. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qREcv.png).

Error:

```
_Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Application\Controller\OutcomeController in **C:\wamp\www\PersonalFinance\module\Users\src\Users\Controller\OutcomeController.php** on line 33_
```

`OutcomeController` class code is as follow:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;


/**
     * OutcomeController
     *
     * @author
     *
     * @version
     *
     */
    class OutcomeController extends AbstractActionController
    {

        /**
         * The default action - show the home page
         */
        public function indexAction()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated OutcomeController::indexAction() default action
            return new ViewModel();
        }

        public function fooAction()
        {
            // This shows the :controller and :action parameters in default route
            // are working when you browse to /income/income/foo
            return array();
        }
    }
```

I've also added the below line to the `autoload_classmap.php` file:

```
'Users\Controller\OutcomeController' => __DIR__ . '/src/Users/Controller/OutcomeController.php',
```

So:

- I've added the controller using the wizard
- I've added the needed
  controller configs to the `module.config.php`
- I've added the
  autoloading config line to the `autoload_classmap.php`

Any ideas why the error happens?

Comment: The error clearly says that class "Outcome Controller" is already declared somewhere else in your project, so insure this will not happen. Also  please check that within same namespace you define this class twice? If yes, remove one.

Comment: Isn't there "previously declared" in the error? This will help you track the problem

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, the class `Application\Controller\OutcomeController` is already defined somewhere else in your application.

This has nothing to do with using the wizard of ZendStudio, configuring correctly ZF2 or with autoloading. This is a PHP thing: you can't have in your application two classes with the same name (considering the namespace).

To avoid the problem you could either change the name of the class or change the namespace where you declare it.